# JSON highcharts -> empty chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have JSON data generated by preparejsongrapf.php with MySQL and the output is this JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "date",
        "data": [
            "Date.UTC(2013,7,30)",
            "Date.UTC(2013,8,5)",
            ...........,
            "Date.UTC(2013,10,29)"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "solde",
        "data": [
            17985.76,
            17865.76,
            17820.13,
            ...........,
            2867.88
        ]
    }
]
```

I think that my syntax of JSON is good and the highcharts script is:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'graphsolde',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25,
                    zoomType: 'x',
                    spacingRight: 20
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'CDN',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    categories: [{}],
                    maxZoom: 14 * 24 * 3600000, // fourteen days
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Solde'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                                           }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                        fillColor: {
                            linearGradient: {x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                            stops: [
                                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                            ]
                        },
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        shadow: false,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        },
                        threshold: null
                    }
                },
                series: [{}]
            }
            $.getJSON("preparejsongrapf.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
    </script>
</script><div id="graphsolde" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
```

The chart appears in the screen but without JSON data.
What is wrong in the getjson?

Comment: How your JSON looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

Compare your JSON to Highchart data format. Please check your JSON format and Highchart series format. Highchart has a separate format to give an input.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this - iterate over the array:

```
$.getJSON('chart_helpers/acme_charthelper.php?callback=?', function(data) {

                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    var series = {data: []};

                    if (key == 'Inbound' || key == 'Outbound') {
                        series.dataGrouping = {enabled: false};

                        series.name = key;

                        if (key == 'Inbound') {
                            series.color = "#85d635";
                        }
                        else {
                            series.color = "#59d5ff";
                        }

                        $.each(value, function(key, val) {

                            series.data.push([key * 1000, val]);

                        });
                        options.series.push(series);
                    }

                    if (key === 'Max') {

                        series.type = 'flags';

                        $.each(value, function(key, val) {
                            series.title = 'Max: ' + val + ' Calls';

                            series.data.push([key * 1000, val]);
                            max = val;
                        });
                        options.series.push(series);
                    }

                });

                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This `"Date.UTC(2013,7,30)", ..` is so wrong.. That is just string, if you want to pass date, use timestamp. So on your serverside, generate timestamp in milliseconds, like this :

```
"Date.UTC(2013,7,30)" -> 1377820800000
```